# Highlighting cells in column A if column B contains the correct value in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a cell in column A to be highlighted if the corresponding cell in column B contains a certain value.
It's easy enough conditional formatting column B on its own but I would like to carry the colour across to column A no matter what value is in the A column.

Say "Joe" is working sat, sun, mon and not working tue, wed, thu, fri, his name is in column B across from the the days he is working labeled in column A. I would like to highlight the days as well as his name whenever he is "working".

I hope this makes sense.
I look forward to hearing if anybody has created or used a formula in this way before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set conditional formatting in `A2` based on a formula, so set the formula to something like the following:

```
=B2="Joe"
```

To copy over the conditional formatting to the other cells, I selected the range and used `Ctrl+Y` to redo the conditional formatting. It changed the formula to match the current cell.

Note: I did this in Excel XP, as I don't have Excel 2010 in front of me.

Comment: Thankyou Zev, the formula work fine in 2010, just couldn't get ctrl y to work but that was a minor issue. Your answer is much appricated

Answer (score 0):

To format both columns (as requested), select ColumnA:B, clear existing CF rules from them and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$B1="Joe"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

For me also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> does not here work for copying down, let alone the copy across aspect.